# How to download PDF from pubs.acs.org using Python?

Tags: python

I've got a list I'd like to download quickly in Python. How can I do it? Here is the list:

```
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.fw001
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.pr001
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch001
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch002
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch003
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch004
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch005
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch006
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch007
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch008
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch009
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch010
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch011
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch012
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch013
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch014
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch015
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch016
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch017
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch018
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch019
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch020
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch021
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch022
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch023
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch024
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch025
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch026
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch027
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch028
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch029
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch030
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch031
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch032
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ot001
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ot002
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ot003
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ot004
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ot005
pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ix002
```

This is a bit different for me. I'm used to just having .pdf files on the page. Anyway, my university pays for access, and I want to download the whole thing quickly. Not manually…

---

I tried the following, but when I try to open the PDF in my local directory, I get an error message:

```
import urllib2

pdf_urls = [
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.fw001', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.pr001', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch001', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch002', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch003', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch004', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch005', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch006', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch007', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch008', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch009', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch010', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch011', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch012', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch013', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch014', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch015', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch016', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch017', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch018', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch019', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch020', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch021', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch022', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch023', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch024', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch025', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch026', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch027', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch028', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch029', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch030', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch031', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ch032', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ot001', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ot002', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ot003', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ot004', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ot005', 
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.ix002'
]


for pdf_url in pdf_urls:
    response = urllib2.urlopen('http://' + pdf_url)
    output_name = pdf_url.rpartition('.')[2] + '.pdf'

    output_file = open(output_name, 'wb')
    output_file.write(output_name)
```

To be honest, I don't think I know what I'm doing...

Comment: 1. it is illegal to download those things by script (in my country at least) and 2. I can't see any effort of yours.

Comment: `grep -o '\/doi\/pdf/[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{4\}\/[a-z]\{2\}\-[0-9]\{4\}\-[0-9]\{4\}\.[a-z]\{2\}[0-9]\{3\}' test.txt | sed 's/^/pubs\.acs\.org/g' | sed 's/^/    /g' | pbcopy` is my effort so far… ^ _ ^

Comment: Well, like I mentioned, this is new to me. What is .ix002 anyway? How do I handle this in Python? What is it?

Comment: What entity am I dealing with?

Comment: it's a pdf, `bk-2012-1093.ch032` and similar are just names. And `grep -o` is not python.

Comment: You don't "handle it in python", you simply download it. By opening the url and writing the resulting response to a file. Just google for "python download file" to see how.

Comment: I'm aware of `grep` not being Python. You asked for work, and I was being a smart ass.

Comment: I've got a library of Python resources on how to write files. So you are saying to just write the results of each link as a file to my main directory?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) library for Python:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()

pdf_urls = [
    'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.fw001',
    'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.pr001'
    #and other files....
]


for pdf_url in pdf_urls:
    r = session.get('http://' + pdf_url)

    output_name = pdf_url.rpartition('.')[2] + '.pdf'
    output_file = open(output_name, 'wb')
    output_file.write(r.content)
```

This code will save files in the same directory where Python script is.

**EDIT:**
Code with **urllib2**:

```
import urllib2
from cookielib import CookieJar

pdf_urls = [
'pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.fw001'
]

cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

for pdf_url in pdf_urls:

    response = opener.open('http://' + pdf_url)
    content = response.read()

    output_name = pdf_url.rpartition('.')[2] + '.pdf'
    output_file = open(output_name, 'wb')
    output_file.write(content)
```

**Some explanations:** 
First of all, `http://pubs.acs.org/` requires that browser (or python script in our case) accepted cookies. We can do it with `CookieJar`:

```
cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
```

In the loop, we iterate across urls list and download files:

```
response = opener.open('http://' + pdf_url)
content = response.read()
```

***content*** contains single pdf file. Save it. To start, generate a file name for the recording. [rpartition](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) returns a three element tuple,

- 1st element being the string before the separator
- the separator itself
- the string after the separator

So, for example,

'`pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2012-1093.fw001'.rpartition('.')[2]` 
gives us `fw001`. And we add `.pdf` extension to file name. Then we open file in binary mode for writing:

```
output_file = open(output_name, 'wb')
```

And write a pdf file obtained from the site

```
output_file.write(content)
```

Comment: Hmm… `requests` doesn't seem to work on my machine...

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: I'm looking for something that uses the standard modules in Python.

Comment: You can use `urllib2` module. But `requests` is more simple.

Comment: See my most recent edit.

Comment: The code I use at the bottom of the OP works. It downloads the files, but when I open them, I get a message saying they are corrupt. Each file is 9 bytes...

Comment: Problem with your code is that you **do not actually download anything** and save into pdf file simply file name, i.e. plain text :). Of couse, it is not correct pdf file, and when you open this file, you get error. Well, I rewrote my code with `urllib2`. It will save files correctly. Try it!